# Increase the space between the table relative to the text above and below

Tags: tabularray

I use the tabularray package to create the table. But I see that the vertical space between the table and the text above and below the table is small. I used headsep but it didn't work. How can I increase that distance. I don't want to use vspace more than once, because in my document there are many similar tables.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray-2021,lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={XXX},hlines,vlines}
        a & b & c\\
        c & d & e
    \end{tblr}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option `\SetTblrOuter`, using e.g. `\SetTblrOuter{long}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray-2021,lipsum}
\SetTblrOuter{long}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={XXX},hlines,vlines}
        a & b & c\\
        c & d & e
    \end{tblr}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer. No need hacking  with `\bigskip`.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this is helpful to you, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray-2021,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}{\bigskip}
\AtEndEnvironment{tblr}{\bigskip}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={XXX},hlines,vlines}
        a & b & c\\
        c & d & e
    \end{tblr}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks for helping me.

Comment: @NguyễnCảnhDũng Thanks for your kind words, if my answers suits with you, then please accept this answer by click the `tick` mark.

Comment: I see a "tick" with no link.

Comment: Just click it and see

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\bigskip` to increase the distance.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray-2021,lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \bigskip
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={XXX},hlines,vlines}
        a & b & c\\
        c & d & e
    \end{tblr}
    
   \bigskip
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Initially, I too thought to apply `\bigskip`, but later, I've changed my mind, ha ha ha. :-D